# knapsack code is not working in python while submitting it in GFG

Tags: python, data-structures, knapsack-problem

I am trying to solve GeeksforGeeks problem [0 - 1 Knapsack Problem](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/0-1-knapsack-problem0945/1)
:

> You are given weights and values of **N** items, put these items in a knapsack of capacity **W** to get the maximum total value in the knapsack. Note that we have only **one quantity of each item**.
>
> In other words, given two integer arrays **val[0..N-1]** and **wt[0..N-1]** which represent values and weights associated with **N** items respectively. Also given an integer **W** which represents knapsack capacity, find out the maximum value subset of **val[]** such that sum of the weights of this subset is smaller than or equal to **W**. You cannot break an item, **either pick the complete item or don't pick it (0-1 property)**.

My code fails some test cases:

```
#User function Template for python3
t=[[ -1 for j in range(1001)] for i in range(1001)]

class Solution:
    #Function to return max value that can be put in knapsack of capacity W.
    def knapSack(self,W, wt, val, n):
        if n==0 or W==0:
            return 0
        if t[n][W]!=-1:
            return t[n][W]
        if wt[n-1]<=W:
            t[n][W]=max(val[n-1]+self.knapSack(W-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1), 
            self.knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1))
            return t[n][W]
        elif wt[n-1]>W:
            t[n][W]=self.knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1)
            return t[n][W]
            
#{ 
 # Driver Code Starts
#Initial Template for Python 3
import atexit
import io
import sys

# Contributed by : Nagendra Jha

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_cases = int(input())
    for cases in range(test_cases):
        n = int(input())
        W = int(input())
        val = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
        wt = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
        ob=Solution()
        print(ob.knapSack(W,wt,val,n))
# } Driver Code Ends
```

I tried multiple things, but I cannot get it to pass the tests. When I run it with the example input, it works fine, but when I submit the code, it always fails on the second test case. Yet when I take the input of that second case and run it with only that test case, it works. I am puzzled... I want to use the memoization technique (`t`). What am I doing wrong here?

NB: I know how to solve it with a top-down approach, but I would like to see my memoization approach work as well.

Comment: 1) Do not tag `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is used for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.  2) Why didn't you tag this as `python`?  By not giving the correct tag, hardly anyone will see your question.

Comment: I would like to help you but what is the problem really? One of the test cases.... sounds like you're doing homework for school?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the global `t` variable: it will be used for more than one test case, and so the results of one run will leak into the next run.

You need to make `t` either an instance member of `Solution` (assuming that the GFG instanciates a new `Solution` object for each run), or make it a local variable and use a local function for the recursive part of your algorithm.

Not a problem, but:

- I would have only one `return` statement at the end of the recursive function, since it is the same for all three cases.
- The `elif` can be just `else` since it is supposed to cover the remaining cases

Here is how the second approach would look:

```
class Solution:
    
    def knapSack(self, W, wt, val, n):
        # Define the memoization structure locally, so it is reset for every run:
        t = [ [-1 for j in range(W + 1)] for i in range(n + 1) ]
        
        def knapSackHelper(W, n):
            if n == 0 or W == 0:
                return 0
            if t[n][W] == -1:
                if wt[n-1] <= W:
                    t[n][W] = max(val[n-1] + knapSackHelper(W - wt[n-1], n-1), 
                                  knapSackHelper(W, n-1))
                else:
                    t[n][W] = knapSackHelper(W, n-1)
            return t[n][W]
            
        return knapSackHelper(W, n)
```